# eclipse dark theme cannot show the tab property

Tags: eclipse, themes

when using eclipse Dark Theme, some tab is very difficult to see its content as it show all white as below (the red highlighted), any method to prevent it?

[image]

Comment: You are using an outdated Eclipse version.

Comment: my eclipse version is 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id:20190314-1200
Later version has fixed this issue?

Comment: The current version is 2019-12 (4.14) with 2020-03 (4.15) due soon.

Comment: This issue is not related of using an outdated Eclipse version (as you can see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.11/platform.php#dark-theme-windows)). Please upgrade and see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

These colors can be configured and are not the default colors of the dark theme. This misconfiguration could have been done manually or happened by installing or using a third-party plug-in.

You can see if it is a misconfiguration by switching to a new workspace without copying the settings.

In this case, go to ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** edit the color in ***View and Editor Folders*** or hit ***Restore Defaults***.

Comment: I don't understand "You can see if it is a misconfiguration by switching to a new workspace without copying the settings.", I try to swithc to new workspace, it change to Light Theme, Default "Color and Font them", then what to do? change it to dark theme to see same problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

go to Window > Preferences > Appearance
-there you can select dark background
-click on "Apply and Close"
now to get the tabs working go to Window > Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts
edit the following and set to color black
-Active (no focus), selected part foreground
-Active selected part foreground
-Inactive, selective part foreground
-click on "Apply and Close"

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the full effect takes place after we restart eclipse.